# Having "now playing" automatically sync between my iPod Touch (4G) and iTunes 10.5

Tags: itunes, sync, ipod-touch

Okay... here's what I want to do:

Play some music on my iPod Touch while I'm on the road. When I come home, and into the range of my WI-FI network that I can seamlessly pick up my (Windows 7) laptop with iTunes 10.5 installed and running, and have the music that started on my iPod continue on my laptop; and vice-versa.

The "Remote" app is handy, but doesn't really do what I want to do; neither does "WIFI2HIFI" which is a cool app. nonetheless.

I truly hope someone can help me with this. It seems like such an easy thing to ask for, but 4 days of Google searches haven't come up with what I'm looking for.